# How to join complex sql queries within a table using subqueries

Tags: sql, join

I have a table with "userid", "bookid", "sessionid".

When a book(bookid) is viewed by a visitor(userid), the web application will find all books(bookids) viewed by users(userids) who viewed this book(bookid) and display the top 5 books.

Comment: Great.  Do you have a question?

Comment: Just as you did above, then access the properties with book.bookid,  you can also declare multiple properties e.g. book(bookId int, name char(max))

Comment: @GordonLinoff my question is what will be the sql query to retrieve the top 5 books

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume the following:

- You are using MySQL as DBMS.
- With "Top 5 books" you mean "the 5 most viewed books considering the views by the users who viewed the current book".

Assuming as an example that the user is visiting the book 151 at the moment, you can do it with the following query:

```
SELECT bookid, COUNT(*) AS BookViews
FROM YourTable
WHERE userid IN (SELECT userid FROM YourTable WHERE bookid = 151)
GROUP BY bookid
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 5;
```